# ¿Cómo ver página web Visual Studio ASP en localhost de mi equipo en un dispositivo web?

Tags: visual-studio

Tengo una aplicación Web en Visual Studio 2008. Cada vez que hago pruebas esa página la veo en mi equipo con la URL http://localhost:puerto/micarpeta/mi.html

He probado de ver la web en un dispositivo móvil conectado a la misma red del equipo con Visual Studio. Para ello pongo la url http://miequipo:puerto/micarpeta/mi.html, pero no puedo ver la web en el móvil.

Si pongo en el navegador de mi equipo y en el navegador del dispositivo móvil la dirección IP del equipo donde tengo el IIS (es la misma máquina donde tengo el visual studio) me sale correctamente la página de presentación del IIS.

La URL que pongo es una IP local tal como `192.168.0.21`.